# Serial voting has reversed

Tags: support, voting

During this week twice my reputation was changed with message "`Serial voting has reversed`". Now it is only `-40rep.`, last week it was `-725rep.` Two weeks ago any user was deleted, and I *received* `-10rep.` I don´t know who was deleted, what he did here but I obtain any rep. for my answer. Answer probably stay here on this server, probably help to the others, but I have `-10rep.`

OK, back to "`reversed voting`".

I´ve read what does it mean, but I really don´t know why I was penalized. I have here one account (this one), I do my best here and help to others (in my free time). I try to increase SO standard submitting suggested edits, editing wrong posts, etc. And prize for my time? Decrease my reputation. Who is able to make a judgement that I´m a vote-cheater? Who? Moderators?

I know neither who votes for my posts, nor why votes for my posts. I know nothing, only that I was penalized because of someone, because of anonymnous user and someone of moderators.

I don´t do this because of high reputation points here, I help others because the helped me when I began my career (I read answers to questions, I didn´t ask directly) and now it´s time to help others, to new generation. But with this access, degrading my participation, I think about stop post new answers and comments.

So, is there any way how to return me my reputation I gained here for my knowledge a my time?

I hope you understand me, and it´s possible to revert this.

Comment: You were 'penalised' when another user decided to upvote everything in sight. That is not allowed. The serial voting script reverted this.

Comment: Do you *really* want us to go into details in public?

Comment: @Chris: I have no problem with that. Or you can write me to my mail, I suppose you see that in my profile.

Comment: Well the fact that your account doesn't appear to be suspended would indicate that the mods didn't feel you were complicit in the voting fraud.  The action was simply reversed and only the fraudulent votes were removed.  If they felt that you were complicit in the voting fraud one would expect that they'd have done more to your account than just reverse the votes.

Comment: @Servy - it was totally automatic. There were no mods involved - until now.

Comment: @ChrisF The deleted user seemed like a plausible instance of mod intervention.

Comment: @Servy - the message was "Serial voting reversed" NOT "user removed". So it's nothing to do with a user being deleted. Ah - I've just seen that there was a "user removed" message earlier.

Comment: @ChrisF He mentioned both, and I see instances of both in his reputation history.

Comment: @Servy - Indeed. Though that's not really the issue here.

Answer (score 16):

The system spotted that a particular user was upvoting your content in suspicious manner so reversed those upvotes - twice. Further investigation of the account that was doing the serial upvoting has revealed some things that I don't want to discuss in public, but which make me think that there may be more than it just someone being a fan.

Voting based on the owner of the post is not the way Stack Overflow works. You should be voting on the content not the author, and going through a users profile voting on everything they've posted is not the way to reward good content. Neither is it the way to mark down poor content.

When votes are removed (either serial votes or by users being removed) then it's as if those votes *had never happened* so there's no reputation to restore. It's like it was never there.

Comment: Ok, I respect you don´t want to discuss that in public. Can we move to e-mail, please?

Comment: @panther I have sent you a message. Please read it and consider everything that it tells you.

Comment: I tried to reply you there, it goes to error while sending. So:

Really don´t know who can be the second one.

I have many colleagues (hundreds) and don´t know that anyone goes to stackoverflow too. Sure, for asnwers, they are searching here answers but I don´t know anybody who has here a profile and goes here regurarly. I think, nobody of them goes here regurarly. But... I really don´t know.

So, can you, Chris, tell me, who is it? If it is anybody from my colleagues, I can speak with him.

Comment: Sure, it´s possible that sb. wanted to "help" me. I asked nobody for this "service", it´s the only one thing I´m sure.

Comment: @panther - can you report the error here on Meta. You should be able to reply to a mod message. As for the details, I really can't disclose them publicly.

Comment: We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.

It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.

It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Can you sent me via private message name, mail or link to user account? Whatever?

Comment: @panther all communications should be within Stack Overflow so that there is a trail of who said what, when and to whom. Taking communications outside of SO is not allowed.

Comment: And can you send me link to his (I suppose it´s a guy, we have only three girls here) account? Without more details, just link?

Comment: @panther - I can't do that. I will however, send him a message.

Comment: @panther I don't see your email/web/whatever contact info in your profile.  Why is that?

Comment: @Martin: my email is set as "private", I supposed Moderators are able to see that (I don´t need to receive a mail messages from the other ones). And my website is empty because I have no own website. Is it problem? I don´t know what you meant by this comment.

Comment: Take it with pride. You've got a fan :) I've got a few myself... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283345/serial-vote-reverse-option-has-not-reversed-all-the-malicious-actions

Comment: @ChrisF Your last paragraph; that's not true anymore. Some user was serial upvoting me yesterday, and today *most* of their downvotes (bar one downvote) was reversed (was definitely the same user- seems to be a common bug in the reversal script not to reverse serial votes if they occur one minute after the other votes). In my reputation history the downvotes still showed, but my profile simply gave me the rep back with 'Serial voting reversed'). I can still see that someone serial downvoted.