# "serial vote reverse" option has not reversed all the malicious actions

Tags: support, serial-voting

I experienced some sudden drop of my reputation. Someone has down voted lot of questions asked by myself (I can guess the person. It was for taking revenge). But Stack overflow serial down voting tracking system has reversed it. But I did not recover all the reputation. (I lost 10 reputation, but got back only 6) I read on Meta, but I was not able to find an answer too.

Here is a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: But I am quite sure, there is the same person behind this. Because I have seen that he has used some fake profiles to vote-up (rate) his own articles. This is not ethical. What can I do for get my reputation back? Thank you.

Comment: If you're really sure that the downvoter is using multiple "sock-puppet" accounts, [flag one of their posts for moderator attention.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259949/is-there-a-mechanism-to-detect-sock-puppets#comment39606_259949)

Answer (score 6):

Serial down-voting is done by a single person.

You had a total of -6 reputation on a single post (Jquery/JavaScript - Store Ajax jSONP response), and the other -4 came from two other posts.

A single person must have downvoted all 3 posts, resulting in -6 reputation (which was returned). The other -4 on your Jquery post must have been from other people, as the serial-downvoter couldn't have downvoted your post more than one.

Those -4 won't be returned as they weren't done by the same person.

Comment: But I am quite sure, there is the same person behind this. Because I have seen that he has used some fake profiles to vote-up (rate) his own articles. This is not ethical. What can I do for get my reputation back? Thank you.

Comment: @KushanRandima - For the record, I looked into this and I see no evidence of sock puppet accounts being used by the person behind this voting (I have very good tools for finding this out). I believe these other votes are indeed coincidental.

Comment: I am sorry, I figured out your answer after two years. I do not know how I miss the notification for your comment. By the way, thanks for your consideration.